# The Entity type <T> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have tested the other tables in the model and they are working. However, I added two new tables and they are not in the model.

How do I ensure that a database table is part of the model?

`OnModelCreating` is NOT called in this code.
[image]

```
The entity type AppToLeadRequestLine is not part of the model for the current context.
```

This exception is thrown when adding an item to the table.

```
public void Add<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
   Set<T>().Add(obj);
}
```

I added both of these tables to the database.

[image]

After adding these two tables to the database I generated them in the model by using `Update Model from Database`, and both tables appear in the model.
[image]

When I look at the table mapping they appear to be mapped to the correct POCO. I'm not 100% sure about this.

[image]
[image]

The classes look like this: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: That error can mean a few things.  Can you verify your other tables are working correctly, and it's just that one or two that aren't?

Comment: I have tested the other tables and they are working. Only the two new tables that I added are having this issue.

Comment: How can `LeadDeliveryTimes` be `TimeSpan` in the class model, while it shows a `bigint/Int64` in the mapping?

Comment: I think I put in the wrong picture, updating now.

Comment: The `AppToLeadRequestLine` class shows `Status` with a type of `AppToLeadRequestStatus`, whereas the mapping screenshot above shows `Status` with a type of `int` on the table side and `Int32` on the poco side ... perhaps the edmx doesn't like that discrepancy?

Comment: Good eye, I didn't catch that! I'm making a small project to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnModelCreating` is not called -- as you pointed out -- so I can be certain that you are using a Model-First approach (and *not* Code-First).  In this case, you are responsible for *all* of the mapping.  [Here is a good article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

It appears that `RequestId` is a foreign key to the `AppToLeadRequest` class -- if this is the case, you must declare the `public virtual` statements in both classes yourself.

For example -- at the bottom of the `AppToLeadRequest` class, it should contain:

`public virtual ICollection<AppToLeadRequestLine> AppToLeadRequestLines { get; set; }`

and, at the bottom of the `AppToLeadRequestLine` class, it should contain:

`public virtual AppToLeadRequest AppToLeadRequest { get; set; }`

I would also change `RequestId` to `AppToLeadRequestId` to follow a `<class name>Id` format.